# How to add JSP form data into a JSON object and store it in a database?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I have a user entry form with the following fields :

- Name
- Age
- Address

I want to convert its value to JSON and save it in a database. How can I achieve this?
Which library can I use ?

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  And if you're storing a JSON string in a local DB you should generally store it as a "blob".  (Though why use JSON in the first place, vs storing Name/Age/Address as 3 separate columns?)

Answer (score 1):

At server side in servlet save all request parameters to corresponding bean and then  you can convert using google's **gson library** for more info check this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

1. You need servlet that takes form submission
2. To work with JSON I recommend eclipse source minimal JSON, I like it
3. database - plain JDBC, hibernate or JPA ..

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following steps:

1. In JSP page, at javascript convert the form fields to JSON using **JSON.stringify()** method.
2. At server parse the JSON using appropriate JSON parsers like **GSON** or **Jackson**.
3. After parsing you will get **desired object**.
4. Perform **database operation** on the object.

You will probably need **GSON** jar , **Jackson** jar.